# Problems with CSS in Firefox

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a below CSS which works well with Google Chrome, but not with Firefox.

```
$document->addStyleDeclaration('body{margin-bottom:65px!important} 
.toolbar_fixed{position:fixed;left:1px;bottom:-5px;width:100%!important} 
.toolbar_fixed_inner{style="height:100%;width:100%;background:'.$params->get('background').';border-top:'.$params->get('border_pixels').'px solid '.$params->get('border_color').';color:#202020}
.toolbar_fixed_content{text-align:'.$params->get('align').';width:100%;margin-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:5px}
.toolbar_fixed_content a:hover{background:none!important}
.toolbar_fixed_content img{margin-right:'.$params->get('images_space').'px}
');
```

You'll get to know the difference if you check this link (Bottom Bar with Social Media Icons) in Google Chrome and Firefox.
http://www.joomla357.com/demo/toolbar-joomla-module.html

Please let me know how can I get same for firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what syntax this is, but probably this line

```
.toolbar_fixed_inner{style="height:100%;width:100%;background:'.$params->get('background').';border-top:'.$params->get('border_pixels').'px solid '.$params->get('border_color').';color:#202020}
```

is incorrect. Try removing the style=".. part

```
.toolbar_fixed_inner{height:100%;width:100%;background:'.$params->get('background').';border-top:'.$params->get('border_pixels').'px solid '.$params->get('border_color').';color:#202020}
```

and give it a try

Comment: But if this is a problem , why it works fine with google chrome ?

Comment: could be possible that chrome just ignores this part and firefox is more strict.

Comment: Yeah, chrome goes that extra mile but the syntax is definitely wrong.